# Detailed explanation needed for basic query regarding expectation

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

I need to find the expectation of following random variable $$g=[\log_2(\frac{1+x}{1+y})]^+$$ where $[x]^+=max(x,0)$ and both $x,y$ variables depend on variable $z$. I know the conditional pdf's and cdf's of $x$ and $y$ conditioned on $z$. I want to know how can we prove the following $$E[g]=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{F_{y|z}(x_2)}{1+x_2}(1-F_{x|z}(x_2))f_{z}(x_1)dx_2dx_1$$ where $F's$ are the cdf and $f's$ are pdf. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We use capital letters for random variables, as is customary. Note that $$\left(\log_2\left(\frac{1+X}{1+Y}\right)\right)^+=\frac1{\log2}\left(\log(1+X)-\log(1+Y)\right)\mathbf 1_{Y<X}$$
hence $$G=\frac1{\log2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+t}\mathbf 1_{Y<t<X}dt$$
which implies $$E(G\mid Z)=\frac1{\log2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+t} P(Y<t<X\mid Z)dt$$
**Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent conditionally on $Z$**, one has $$P(Y<t<X\mid Z)=P(Y<t\mid Z)P(X>t\mid Z)=F_{Y\mid Z}(t\mid Z)(1-F_{X\mid Z}(t\mid Z))$$ hence ...

Comment: $$E(G)=E(E(G\mid Z))=\frac1{\log2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+t}E(F_{Y\mid Z}(t\mid Z)(1-F_{X\mid Z}(t\mid Z)))dt$$ and, finally, if $Z$ has PDF $f_Z$, one sees that, as desired, $$E(G)=\frac1{\log2}\int_0^\infty\int_\mathbb R\frac{1}{1+t}F_{Y\mid Z}(t\mid u)(1-F_{X\mid Z}(t\mid u))f_Z(u)dudt.$$

Comment: This thing look like some secrecy capacity stuff. Could you kindly give me the full expression of x and y with respect to z ?